# Adding custom action menu to Acumatica Customer form

Tags: acumatica

I think this is probably just something stupid, but I'm trying to add a custom menu to the Customer form. I've used this code:

```cs
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        this.SpeedyActions.AddMenuAction(BtnCreateMenu1);
        this.SpeedyActions.AddMenuAction(BtnCreateMenu2);
    }

    public PXAction<PX.Objects.AR.Customer> BtnCreateMenu1;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Menu Item 1")]
    protected void btnCreateMenu1()
    {

      // Logic

    }

    public PXAction<PX.Objects.AR.Customer> BtnCreateMenu2;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Menu Item 2")]
    protected void btnCreateMenu2()
    {

      // Logic

    }      

    public PXAction<PX.Objects.AR.Customer> SpeedyActions;
    [PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.Report, MenuAutoOpen =true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Speedy Actions")]
    protected void speedyActions()
    {
       //code logic here
    }
```

I've got basically the same code on the sales order form and it works perfectly. I suspect that I'm maybe using the wrong code here `PX.Objects.AR.Customer` and I've also tried CR.BAccount, but can't seem to make it work. Anyone have some thoughts?

Comment: Hi @T-Rav, your code works correctly on my environment. https://imgur.com/a/0ma2aY9
What is the result in yours?

Comment: Huh, so apparently this is just my ignorance. I had a customization after that that also had code (but none that I thought should be overlapping) on the Customer form and that made it not work. This is probably an question that reveals my ignorance, but can there only be one customization for each screen?

Comment: You should be able to have multiple customizations associated to the one screen. Different customization packages from different sources may customize the same screen. For your case, try and merge the customizations to see if the error persists. If so, it's something else that is causing the button to not appear

Comment: Thanks. I'll just have to play and see what's killing me. Before I make a new question, if I wanted to have it in the actions menus after "Create Sales Order" is that possible?  I have         this.Base.action.AddMenuAction(BtnCreateMenu2); but don't see how I get that in the location I want.

Comment: good question. I don't know if that's possible though. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would try

Base.report.AddMenuAction(BtnCreateMenu1)